# Usage of cell style

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm working on a import module from a excel file. I have to read and check this file, if something is wrong I have to color the corrisponding cell of a color. Then  I implemented the following method

```
public void fillCell(Workbook wb, Row row, int errorColumn){

    Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
    CellStyle cs =  wb.createCellStyle();
    cs.setFillForegroundColor((short) 10);
    cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);          
    cell.setCellStyle(cs);


}
```

but i noted that this method changes the data format of the cell. For example if I'm coloring a cell with data value 29/03/2014 i get the colored cell but its value now is 39536, the same thing happen with the numeric value 1534000001629, also in this case i get the colored cell  but if i try to change the value from 1534000001629 to 1534000001630 i get 1,534+E12.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Cell styles include formatting rules, so you'll need to save those too!

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that cell styles don't only control the colour of a cell, they also control the formatting applied to it. So, what's happening is that you're replacing a cell style that eg formats as #.#%, and instead applying one that's eg red but has no number/date formatting rules applied to it.

Cell styles are workbook scoped, so you shouldn't create one per cell, thus you should make your logic somewhat like:

```
// Lookup from number format to the coloured version
Map<String,CellStyle> styles = new Hashmap<String,CellStyle>();

// Method to make the cell a different colour
public void fillCell(Workbook wb, Row row, int errorColumn){
   Cell cell = row.getCell(j);

   // Try to find a coloured one for this data formatting
   String formatStr = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
   CellStyle cs = styles.get(formatStr);
   if (cs == null) {
      // Need to create a new coloured one
      cs =  wb.createCellStyle();
      cs.setFillForegroundColor((short) 10);
      cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
      cs.setDataFormat(
           wb.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat(formatStr));
      // Save this for later
      styles.put(formatStr, cs);
   }

   // Apply the coloured form, with the format string  
   cell.setCellStyle(cs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either convert it to a string if you don't need to do any date processing on it later as so:

```
cell.setCellType(CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

therwise you may be able to do it by getting the date value from the cell into Java.Util.Date object and then saving it bacl=k:

```
Date date=cell.getDateCellValue();
//colour change
cell.setValue(date);
```

I don't have time to test this right now but let me know if it works and if not I'll look more into it.

You can get more information [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue%28%29)